# Calling C++ function from a C file in Android

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am doing development in Android using C/C++. I have a C++ function, that needs to be called from a C file. Here is what I am doing right now, but I get the error

> undefined reference to `__check_expiry`

The C++ function is defined in "a.h" and implemented in "a.cpp". I am including "a.h" in"b.c" file and calling the method "`__check_expiry`" from "b.c" file.

a.h :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static int __check_expiry(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} 
#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
extern "C" {

static int __check_expiry() {

    vz::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex_check, lock_hooker_check);

    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    static bool __is_attached_1 = false;

    if ((env = __getEnv(&__is_attached_1)) == NULL) {
        //log_info("getEnv fail\r\n");
    }
    assert(!__is_attached_1);

    int obj = env->CallStaticIntMethod((jclass) g_class, g_methodID);
    log_info("Returned value from JAVA %d", obj);

    __releaseEnv(__is_attached_1);

    guard.~lock_guard();

    return obj;
}

}
```

b.c:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "a.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

static int tunnel_to()
{
    int value = __check_expiry();
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that you aren't allowed to use names starting with a double underscore, or an underscore followed by a capital (might be restricted to global names, but I'd avoid them altogether)

Comment: removing the underscores does not help either. Getting the same error.

Comment: remove the `static` on `static int __check_expiry() ` the inner qualifier takes precedence so the name is not exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static functions are not exported. Remove the `static` qualifier.

(Unrelated: as long as you `#include "a.h"` from a.cpp, you don't need the `extern "C"` in your source file.)